# HTML - Centering DIV content

Tags: html, css

I am trying to span and center the content of div using class test1. Spanning the div across the full width of the page works. But centering the content in the div does not. What ever happened to using align=center simply?

```
<style>
    div.test1
    {
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }
    div.test2
    {
        display: inline;
        float: left;
    }
</style>

<div class="test1">
    <div class="test2">This</div>
    <div class="test2">Is</div>
    <div class="test2">A</div>
    <div class="test2">Test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You div is centered. But its also 100% wide...

Comment: you can't centre content of test1 if the content has float attributes.. also, if it's floated you don't need display:inline; either as floating applies this

Comment: @DannyHearnah He is not floating `div.test1`

Comment: @Bondye no he is floating `test2`, which is the content/child of `test1`

Comment: @DannyHearnah So what? ofcourse you are able to center a div which contains floating members. You just need a clearfix.

Comment: @Bondye the floated content will not be centred, only the parent element, the floated content will be aligned to whatever float you have assigned. `test2` will always sit to the left inside `test1` - although reading the OP again i may of misunderstood the request. & So you are correct, the parent is centred, - of course. I was under the impression the request was for the children (`test2`) to be centred within the parent `test1` being 100% width.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
div.test1 {
    text-align: center;
}
div.test2 {
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline; /* IE7 fix for inline-block */
    *zoom: 1;         /* IE7 fix for inline-block */
}
```

[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Matt_Coughlin/tCvPM/1/)

Comment: This sort of gave me the right answer, although I removed the IE 7 fixes and used display:inline. It works for my test I gave, but not for secure data (that I cannot show)

Comment: If you run into styling issues, `display:inline-block` offers greater flexibility and control for styling elements than `display:inline`. In some cases, setting a div to `display:inline` may not work as expected.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
<style>
    div.test1
    {
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        text-align: center;
    }

</style>

<div class="test1">
    <div class="test2">This</div>
    <div class="test2">Is</div>
    <div class="test2">A</div>
    <div class="test2">Test</div>
</div>
```

Comment: the contents of test1 will no longer be aligned next to each other.. hence the OP using floats to align the divs together

Answer (score 2):

> What ever happened to using align=center simply?

The `align` tag [is deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#h-15.1.2). It wouldn't work in this case, anyway.

Use `display: inline-block;` instead of `float: left;` (and remove the `display: inline;` part, of course). Floated elements can *not* be centered.

Comment: You beat me to it by seconds  :) Still, plus 1 as this what I was going to say

Comment: I suspect those downvotes are coming from people who want their answers to float to top. I might be wrong; please feel free to drop a comment.

Answer (score 2):

Just put `<center>` before starting the div and `</center>` after closing the div. Like this:

```
<center>
    <div class="test1">
    <div class="test2">This</div>
    <div class="test2">Is</div>
    <div class="test2">A</div>
    <div class="test2">Test</div>
</div>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use css code :

```
.test1 .test2{
   width:100%;
   text-align:center;
 }
```

best regards

Answer (score 0):

Divs are block level elements. Spans are inline. Consider a larger div and span the smaller elements inside.